# Uniformly integrability and convergence of expectation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value

What I want to prove is that if I have a sequence of random variable $Y_n$ uniformly integrable that converge to Y, so $Y_n\to Y$ then $E[Y_n]\to E[Y]$.

I'm looking at the following proof (after having proved that Y is integrable):

Let $Y_n^\theta=Y_n\mathbb 1_{|Y_n|<\theta}$ and let $Y^\theta=Y\mathbb 1_{|Y|<\theta}$

For all $\theta \in \mathbb R^+$ s.t. $P(|Y|=\theta)=0$ we have $Y_n^\theta \to Y^\theta$ a.s.and $E[Y_n^\theta] \to E[Y^\theta]$

$1)$ why this step follows? and why they hold on $P(|Y|=\theta)=0$?.

Continuing with the proof we thus have: $\limsup |E[Y_n-Y]| \le \limsup \big(|E[Y_n-Y_n^\theta]|+|E[Y_n^\theta-Y^\theta]|+|E[Y^\theta-Y]|\big)$

$2)$ Why this inequality hold?

Going on with the proof I read: since $P(|Y|=\theta)>0$ can be only valid for countably many $\theta$ I can find an increasing sequence $\theta_k$ with $P(|Y|=\theta_k)=0$ and $\theta_k \to \infty.$

$3)$  why $P(|Y|=\theta)>0$ can be only valid for countably many $\theta$? and why I need $P(|Y|=\theta_k)=0$ (this is connected to question $1$)?

I would appreciate a help.

Comment: We can modify the value of $|Y|$ at countably many points without affecting the integral.

Comment: can you better explain your answer? and maybe contextualise it according to my question? thank you

Comment: @Math1000 when we said that "For all $\theta \in \mathbb R^+$ s.t. $P(|Y|=\theta)=0$", it mean that $|Y|=\infty$ with P=1, right?

Comment: 1) because if $Y=\theta$ then $Y_n^{\theta}$ does not converge to $Y^{\theta}$. The convergence of the expectation could be concluded via bounded convergence theorem.  2) it uses triangular inequality repeatedly by adding and subtracting $ Y_n^{\theta}$ and $Y^{\theta}$. 3) the statement said it all. Do you need a proof for that fact? How many points at most can have probability heather than $\frac{1}{2}$? And greater than $\frac{1}{3}$? Can you continue?

Comment: @Kolmo thank you, could you also give a look to my last comment?